# Spring MVC Login Form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created a simple login form that will redirect to the next page after submitting the form credentials. But it's not working fine.
here is my code:

1. Controller class:

> ```
> @RequestMapping("/home")
> public String showForm() {
>     return "home";
> }
>
> @RequestMapping(path = "/handleForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public String handleForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
>
>     String name = request.getParameter("username");
>     String pass = request.getParameter("password");
>     if (name != null && pass != null) {
>         if (name.equals("Twinkle") && pass.equals("twinkle123")) {
>             return "student-list";
>         } else {
>             return "home";
>         }
>     } else {
>         return "error";
>     }
> }
> ```

2. home jsp file:

> ```
> <div class="container mt-5">
>     <h3 class="text-center">Welcome, Login Here</h3>
>
>     <form action="handleForm" method="POST">
>         <div class="form-group">
>
>             <label for="username">User Name</label>
>             <input type="text" class="form-control"
>                    id="username"
>                    placeholder="Enter here"
>                    name="username">
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <label for="password">Password</label>
>             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" minlength="4"
>                    maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter here" name="password">
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="container mt-5 text-center">
>             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
>         </div>
>     </form>
> </div>
> ```

How to fix it?

Comment: What exactly the error/issue is?

Comment: I have done a silly mistake it's now working. The issue was that on clicking the submit button it was not directing to the next page now it's solve.

Comment: By using RequestParam